# Specflow 2.4.0 (not newer) dumping string to Output Tests console

Tags: c#, console, output, specflow

I am using Specflwo 2.4 inside my class with methods that do some actions while doing "feature steps" I would like to drop message to this console:

[image]

I tried to use :

ITraceListener traceListener and invoke methods
traceListener.WriteTestOutput and traceListener.WriteToolOutput

but these dumps the strings to the final test Output (but not to that window)

I tried **pinvoke** apporach - but there is problem with "access denied" occured - also will not pass Code Review

I tried adding **Nunit/Xunit** - dead end - not work, also not acceptable sollution to add yet anothe nuget....
sample code from Nuint - not working

```
NUnit.Framework.TestContext.Progress.WriteLine("NUnit.Framework.TestContext.Progress.WriteLine Some string");
```

I tried such a trick, also is not working:

```
   using (var writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter(System.Console.OpenStandardOutput()))
   writer.WriteLine("This will show up!"); // also is not working
```

CucumberMessages from  SpecFlow/TechTalk.SpecFlow/CucumberMessages/CucumberMessageSender.cs - looks promising but I have to upgrade sepcflow and also usage is... annoying and closer to talking with Deamons/Ghosts not  with Simlpe Output-Tests console

I tried also this

```
    ConsoleTraceListener consoleTracer;
    consoleTracer = new ConsoleTraceListener();
    consoleTracer.Name = "mainConsoleTracer";
    consoleTracer.WriteLine(" Starting output to trace listener .");
```

I also discovered that I can send strings to Debug Console (partial sollution)

```
    Trace.WriteLine("\r\n Trace.WriteLine: Some String ");
    Debugger.Log(0, "1", "Debugger.log message \r\n");
```

I tried sollutions from this forum: https://github.com/microsoft/vstest/issues/799
no success.

Any clues - looks liek Specflow is stealing all output from StdOut (Standard Output) and probbaly StdErr (Standard Error) and redirecting to something that is available after the test.

There was a trick also to use
Please advise.

Comment: SpecFlow doesn't steal StdOut and StdErr. Since some years, the test runners simply don't catch the console output at all. You have to use the API from the unit test framework to make output. Why the NUnit call is  not working, I have no idea. Did you tried it with some of the other TextWriters like Out (https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/TestContext#out)?

Comment: Hello Could You Please be a bit more elaboration and precise. there is list in the sent link a set of static methods and one of them is WriteLine(string somestring). After nunit installation on my solution it is not recognizing this method. in the git repo i could find some examples of Console.WriteLine and it is not working :-(